# Which autocomplete index-time analyzer should I use for non-whitespaced user names?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a relative neophyte when it comes to the usages of ElasticSearch.

Currently, I'm trying to set up autocomplete functionality for the searching of usernames in our app, but I ran into an issue with the completion suggester not giving me the expected results. Here is how I mapped the properties initially.

```
        'properties' : {  
          'username' : {  
            'type' : 'keyword',  
            'fields' : {  
              'text' : {  
                'type' : 'text'  
              },  
              'suggest' : {  
                'type' : 'completion'  
              }  
            }  
          }
        }
```

The usernames will be limited to capitalized alphanumeric characters only. (0-9, A-Z, no whitespace)

The problem I was running into was that the exact match TIM was being weighted the same as 3TIM, due to the default `simple` analyzer. But looking at the standard analyzer, at least according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) seems like only the words between the whitespaces are tokenized.

Can I expect my intended behavior by specifying the standard tokenizer on the username.suggest field? Or am I trying to do this completely wrong and I should be using a totally different analyzer and edge_ngrams instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `completion` field type you normally don't need to use any edge-ngram, that's what the `completion` field does internally.

However, you're right, the `simple` analyzer that's used by default for `completion` types, ditches all the numbers, i.e. it splits the input whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter. So, it would work only if your data only has [a-zA-Z], which is not your case.

Since your input only contains one token usernames, you can use the `standard` analyzer. If there were multiple tokens, I'd discourage you to use it because of the stopwords token filter, but since it's not the case, you're safe to use it.

If you ever have to use completion on a multi token input, what usually works best is to create a `custom` analyzer with either a `whitespace` or `classic` tokenizer and a `lowercase` token filter as shown below:

```
    "suggest_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "classic",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
    },
```

Your mileage may vary, but the above analyzer is a good basis you can build upon.